# For a linear operator $L:V\to V$, $L\neq 0$, $(\exists m\in N)L^m=0$ and $u\in V$ such that $L^{m-1}(u)\neq 0$, prove $L^{m-1}(u)\in KerL\cap ImL$

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{equation}L^m=0 \implies KerL^m=V \implies L^m(u)=0 \tag{1}\end{equation}

$$L^{m-1}(u)=v\neq 0 \tag{2}$$
Multiplying both sides of (2) from the left with $L$ we get $L^m(u)=L(v)$, and replacing $L^m(u)=0$ from (1), we get $L(v)=0$ which proves that $v=L^{m-1}(u)\in KerL$

How do I prove $v=L^{m-1}(u)\in ImL$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L \neq 0$ we have that $m \geq 2$. So we can note $L^{m-1}u = L(L^{m-2}u) \in \mbox{Im}L$

Answer (score 1):

Since $L\neq 0,$ we have $m\geq 2.$ Now let $z= L^{m-2}(u).$ Then we have $v=L(z).$